# Dynamic Controls with radio buttons

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to create a dynamic Website. I created a RadioButton List with four radio buttons. I also created a loop where I created 11 textboxes and then I made an "If" function. I did the same loop with 6 other textboxes. My goal is to display the 11 textboxes when I click on one radio button and the 6 other textboxes when I click on an other radio button. But instead, everything appears when I click on each radio button. **My question is :** **what should I do when I click on one radio button the 11 textboxes appears, and when I click on an other radio button the 6 other textboxes appears ?**

The code below:

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Protected MonRadioButton As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    MonRadioButton.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal
    MonRadioButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(400)
    MonRadioButton.DataSource = Split("Click,OnChanged,Clicked,Changed", ",")
    MonRadioButton.DataBind()
    MonRadioButton.SelectedIndex = 0

    MonRadioButton.AutoPostBack = True

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(MonRadioButton)

    Dim MonTextBox As TextBox

    For i As Integer = 0 To 10

        MonTextBox = New TextBox
        MonTextBox.ID = "TonTextbox" & i
        MonTextBox.Text = MonTextBox.ID

        If MonRadioButton.SelectedValue = "OnChanged" Then

            MonTextBox.AutoPostBack = True

            AddHandler MonTextBox.TextChanged, AddressOf MonTextBox_TextChanged
        End If

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(MonTextBox)
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br>"))

    Next

    MonTextBox.Dispose()

    If MonRadioButton.SelectedValue = "Click" Then
        Dim LeBouton As New Button
        LeBouton.Text = "valider"

        AddHandler LeBouton.Click, AddressOf LeBouton_Click
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(LeBouton)

    End If
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br>"))
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br>"))

    Dim MonTextBox1 As TextBox
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5

        MonTextBox1 = New TextBox
        MonTextBox1.ID = "TxtBox" & i
        MonTextBox1.Text = MonTextBox1.ID

        If MonRadioButton.SelectedValue = "Clicked" Then
            MonTextBox1.AutoPostBack = True
            AddHandler MonTextBox1.TextChanged, AddressOf MonTextBox1_TextChanged
        End If

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(MonTextBox1)
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br>"))

    Next

    MonTextBox1.Dispose()

    If MonRadioButton.SelectedValue = "Changed" Then

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MonTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim LeTextBox As New TextBox
    LeTextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)

    Response.Write("Vous venez de modifié : " & LeTextBox.ID & " avec la valeure : " & LeTextBox.Text)

End Sub

Private Sub MonTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Txtbox As New TextBox
    Txtbox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    Response.Write("Vous venez de modifié : " & Txtbox.ID & " avec la valeure : " & Txtbox.Text())
End Sub

Private Sub LeBouton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim LeTextBox As TextBox
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        Try

            LeTextBox = New TextBox
            LeTextBox = CType(Page.FindControl("TonTextbox" & i), TextBox)

            Response.Write("Texbox N°" & i & " : " & LeTextBox.Text & "<br>")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The if condition to check the selected value of your round button doesnt affect the creation of the textboxes, all you're doing with the roundbuttons its modifying the behaviour and propoerties of the textboxes. This is what you have

```
If roundbutton=something then
  'Here you change the behaviour of the textbox(postback, text, etc.)
Else  

For i = 0 to 5
   'Here you add the textboxes
Next
```

As you see, you're not conditioning the creation to anything, so you need to place your for loop inside your if statement.
For example

```
    If MonRadioButton.SelectedValue = "Clicked" Then
        MonTextBox1.AutoPostBack = True
        AddHandler MonTextBox1.TextChanged, AddressOf MonTextBox1_TextChanged

        For i As Integer = 0 To 5

          MonTextBox1 = New TextBox
          MonTextBox1.ID = "TxtBox" & i
          MonTextBox1.Text = MonTextBox1.ID

          PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(MonTextBox1)
          PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br>"))
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to do what you explained, but it is still not working... If I put the for loop inside the if statement, all the textboxes disappears. But if I add a Else before the for statement, the textboxes are created. But also every textboxes appears, on each radiobutton.